# Object Recognition using Python (OpenCV)

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, rgb, image-recognition

I am trying to implement a program where the user inputs RGB values and the program detects number of objects using OpenCV library. I was able to implement the functionality. However, it works with images made in MS Paint as the color is consistent. However, when I use real world images it doesn't work. How should I implement it using HSV and range of HSV?

I tried the approach on the below mentioned link: https://techvidvan.com/tutorials/detect-objects-of-similar-color-using-opencv-in-python/

```
# lower bound and upper bound for Green color
lower_bound = np.array([50, 20, 20])   
upper_bound = np.array([100, 255, 255])
# find the colors within the boundaries
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_bound, upper_bound)
```

In this case they are able to select a range for green and yellow color. How can I select the range based on the RGB values given by the user?

Comment: [mre] please. that also covers the input data.

Comment: Have you tried to convert the user's RGB input to a point in HSV colour space and then filter for a range around that point?

Comment: @Markus I am able to convert RGB to HSV. However, I do not understand how to get the range once I have the HSV values. Could you help me with that?

Comment: Here in the official tutorial you can find a comprehensive example: https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/da/d97/tutorial_threshold_inRange.html ! If this doesn't solve your issue then please improve your question with more code, example input image etc. so we can understand where exactly you got stuck!